# Xcode unit test warning when declare variable

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

Can anyone explain me why when i declare variable like this:

```swift
private let viewModel = TermsAndConditionViewModel()
    
// TermsAndConditionViewModel

class TermsAndConditionViewModel {

    private let permissionsModel: PermissionsModel
    private let userSession: UserSessionManager
   
    init(
        permissionsModel: PermissionsModel = PermissionsModelImpl(),
        userSession: UserSessionManager = UserSessionManager.shared
    ) {
        self.permissionsModel = permissionsModel
        self.userSession = userSession
    }
}
```

and run test in Xcode I got warning like [image]

update: there is no message about warning.
and this is when I check in Xcode/Coverage

[image]

Thank for your help.

Comment: May you show warning? Your capture image does not show your warning.

Comment: it don't show any information about this warning  @TrầnHữuHiền

Comment: I am still not clearly. Do you want to ask waring in right side, that show "0"? No more detail?

Comment: yah. it don't show any more information.@TrầnHữuHiền

Comment: I will check again, sorry i can't help you now.

Comment: your image showing PermissionsViewController 0 code coverage, but you asking about TermsAndConditionViewModel

Comment: zero with red highlight is because that variable never used/called in unit test

Answer (score 1):

Hi [@user2629744](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2629744/user2629744) welcome to StackOverflow.

The red bar you are seeing in the right gutter is not a warning but [Xcode's Code Coverage Annotation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/07-code_coverage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH15-SW4).

It's red and it shows a `0` because **there is no test exercising that code path**.

It's hard to be sure without having access to your codebase, but since we're talking about a view model in your example I'm guessing that line of code comes from the view layer. Right?

If that's the case, it might be okay if you don't test it. If all the business logic lives in the view model (which you can throughly test) and you keep your view layer [humble](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#HumbleView), then you'll still have the majority of your behavior covered.